# Python SSHTail - Unable to import SSHTailer

Tags: python, import, ssh, tail

I'm using the python-sshtail module to ssh into a linux server and tail a file.

I'm just trying out the sample code (located here: https://github.com/praekelt/python-sshtail) and I'm immediately getting the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name SSHTailer
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

My Install went like this:

```
sshtail-0.0.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for python-sshtail
Searching for paramiko
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/paramiko/
Reading http://www.lag.net/~robey/paramiko/
Reading http://www.lag.net/paramiko/
Best match: paramiko 1.7.7.1
Downloading http://www.lag.net/paramiko/download/paramiko-1.7.7.1.zip
Processing paramiko-1.7.7.1.zip
Running paramiko-1.7.7.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\docume~1\pgajaria\locals~1\temp\easy_install-hp2mfh\paramiko-1.7.7.1\egg-dist-tmp-0_v2ai
warning: no files found matching 'user_rsa_key' under directory 'demos'
warning: no files found matching 'user_rsa_key.pub' under directory 'demos'
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
Adding paramiko 1.7.7.1 to easy-install.pth file
Installed c:\<blanked out>\python\lib\site-packages\paramiko-1.7.7.1-py2.7.egg
```

Finished processing dependencies for python-sshtail

Comment: I have installed it. If I just have "import sshtaiL" for example, I do not receive any errors.

Comment: you're importing using `from sshtail import SSHTailer` ?

Comment: sorry. to clarify, i'm getting an error when I "from sshtail import SSHTailer", but not when i import sshtail. I've also tried copying the class from online and the sample code into the same file and it does work, but I'd really prefer to get the importing working correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I emailed the developer who wrote the library and I got the following response which solved the problem:

> Very strange... It worked fine in my testing. You didn't perhaps call
>   your own script "sshtail.py", did you? In that case, there will be a
>   name conflict with the installed "sshtail" library, resulting in Python
>   trying to import your script instead of the installed library.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work fine for me (Mac OSX Lion, Python 2.7.2). Are you sure you installed python-sshtail correctly?

```
$ mkvirtualenv test-sshtail # optional, of course

... making a virtualenv

(test-sshtail)$ pip install python-sshtail

... installing

(test-sshtail)$ python
Python 2.7.2 (default, Feb  4 2012, 02:01:30) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sshtail import SSHTailer
>>> print "No problem!"
```

Please post more details in case this doesn't help!

Comment: I've edited my original question to show how the install went. it seems to have installed correctly.

Comment: Could it be you're attempting to import it in a different Python environment? For example, if you use [Textmate](http://macromates.com/), you'll find that the version of Python used to run scripts in the editor might not be the same as the one you installed `sshtail` with. Try examining the output of `which python` and `which easy_install` or `which pip`.

Is this the only package you've had trouble installing/importing?

Comment: This is the only package i've had trouble importing. I'm 100% sure the python install is the same one I'm using to run it. Especially since I can type "import sshtail" with no errors